# In all chats, "[Chat.SE]" expands to a Server Fault link

Tags: bug, chat, magic-links

As the title says.

1. Write "[Chat.SE] roflcopter" in the input box.
2. Press enter.
3. Chat message appears, rendered as "[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) roflcopter".

Roflcopter.

Comment: Is this in any chat room or just rooms attached to Server Fault?

Comment: @AdamLear: I've only tried it in rooms that have nothing to do with Server Fault whatsoever (discovered in The Whiteboard).

Comment: @Adam it happens [even here on MSE chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4317584#4317584).

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Haha I like that you kept the "roflcopter"

Comment: Of course, isn't it part of the bug? :-D